# Structure for switchable Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I need to write a Data Access Layer using Entity Framework. One of the requirements is to allow a configuration file to control where the data comes from. With one config setting it should come from a database; with another, from a web service.

Now, my initial thought is to have 3 DataAccess classes:

- WidgetDataAccess
- WidgetDatabaseDataAccess
- WidgetWebServiceDataAccess

They would all implement the same interface. WidgetDataAccess would read the config and delegate to the correct child class. That seems sensible, right?

Is there any pattern that I should follow, or anyone with a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Repository / UnitOfWork pattern.

- **Widget.Core** : Your MVC application using only Widget.DAL namespace, dependency injected  with either Widget.DAL.DatabaseService or Widget.DAL.WebService based on your config file
- **Widget.DAL** : IRepository, IUnitOfWork, IWhateverYouNeed, DTOs
- **Widget.DAL.DatabaseService** : Entity Framework Models and Context. Implementation of Widget.DAL interfaces using your Entity Framework context
- **Widget.DAL.WebService** : Web client, Domain objects, implementations of Widget.DAL interfaces using your Web client

Comment: I read that the Repository pattern is out of favor. Is this something to consider?